# How to return from method when boolean value changes in java?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, blocking

I am developing an app with Flutter which calls some underlying Android code written in java. I have a class with a method, **getScanWifiResult**, which should return a list when a boolean value is changed by another method **wifiReceiver**. Currently, I get stuck at the while loop in **getScanWifiResult**. The code does not move past this while loop to the return the list even though **wifiReceiver** changes the value **resultsUpdated** to *true*. I have tried to use a **volatile** boolean instead, tried to use wait/notify setup, and tried implementing a setup based on jave.utils.concurrent without success. Any ideas to solve the issue in this setup or with a different setup? The overall goal is to return the results list from **getScanWifiResult** list once the method **wifiReceiver** has completed.

```
public final class WifiUtils {
    
    private boolean resultsUpdated = false;
    private List<ScanResult> results;

    private BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            wifiLog("OnReceive in wifiReceiver");
            results = mWifiManager.getScanResults();
            resultsUpdated = true;
            wifiLog("resultsUpdated sat true");
            unregisterReceiver(context, this);
        };
      };

    public List<ScanResult> getScanWifiResult() {

        mWifiManager.startScan();
        registerReceiver(mContext, wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(mWifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));

        while(!resultsUpdated){
            wifiLog("Waiting for resultsUpdated");
        }
  
        return results;
      }

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that this is Android code, and that `getScanWifiResultTest()` is called from the main thread. You cannot block the main thread. You need to change the logic so the code that follows the return from the method can instead be called as a callback, and then provide that callback to this code, so it can be called from the `onReceive()` method. --- Deleted my answer, because that was entirely the wrong approach for Android logic.